# Validation for dropdown boxes selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here My requirement is once we select the SON or Father in one select box and if I select 'Mother-In-law' or 'Father-In_law' in another select boxes,I want one alert message like 'In-laws are not applicable'.

Here is my code,

```
if (arr.indexOf(!(($(this).val() == 'Son' || $(this).val() == 'Father'))) > -1) {
    alert('In-laws are not applicable');
    return false;
}
```

Can any one help me please. The jsFiddle is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/4QUMG/7/).**

-Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check each one of the `selects` looking for `Son` or `Father` after the user selects `Father-in-law` or `Mother-in-law`:

```
if($(this).val()=='Mother-in-law' || $(this).val()=='Father-in-law'){

    //for each of the Relation selects, we check if anyone is Son or Father              
    $('.classSelect').each(function(){
        var currentSelect = $(this).val();
        if( currentSelect == 'Son' ||  currentSelect == 'Father'){
            alert("In-laws are not applicable");  
        }
    });

}
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/4QUMG/10/

## Update

Living example using your `arr` array: http://jsfiddle.net/4QUMG/12/

Also, I would save the value of `$(this).val()` inside a variable.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Then he will know how to make use of it :)

Comment: Clearly not, since he's asking the question :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it is very helped to me,my issue resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, what you want is to see if "Son" or "Father" were already selected, and we're currently selecting an "in-law", to throw the error.

```
if (arr.indexOf('Son') > -1 || arr.indexOf('Father') > -1 && currentVal.indexOf('-in-law') > -1) {
        alert('In-laws are not applicable');
        return false;
    }
```

That code will do that. If you want it to work in reverse, (i.e., we can't select in-law before son or father, either) we'd need to add this:

```
if ((arr.indexOf('Father-in-law') > -1 || arr.indexOf('Mother-in-law') > -1) && (currentVal === 'Son' || currentVal === 'Father')) {
        alert('In-laws are not applicable');
        return false;
    }
```

Also: you could take `$(this).val()` out to a variable at the beginning, so you're not checking it ever time. So just something like `var currentVal = $(this).val()`, and then reference that instead.

Here's a fiddle: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QUMG/11/)**

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it is very helped to me,my issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option. This code is less efficient than the other answers since it will always iterate.

jQuery has two varieties of `$.each(array, function(index, value)...` This works similar to your current loops.

```
var fields = new Array();
$("#dataTable tr select[name^='dRelation']").each(function(i){
    fields.push(this.value);
 });
var rel = $(this).val();
$.each(fields, function(i,val) {
    if((val=='Son' || val=='Father') && (rel == 'Father-in-law' || rel == 'Mother-in-law'))                                 
        alert("yep");
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution,which is helped to me.